# how to download files with ftp url behind http proxy

Tags: c++, qt, proxy, network-programming, qt4

I am behind a http/https proxy. So to download a file using QNetworkAccessManager, i set the proxy as following:

```
    if(no_proxy)
    {
        QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration (false);
        QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy);
    }
    else if(system_proxy)
    {
        QNetworkProxyQuery pQuery(QUrl(QLatin1String("http://www.google.com")));
        QList<QNetworkProxy>listOfProxies =QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery(pQuery);
        QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(listOfProxies.first());
    }
    else if(manual_proxy)
    {
        proxy.setHostName(address);
        proxy.setPort(port);
        if(http_proxy)
            proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
        else if(socks_proxy)
            proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::Socks5Proxy);
        else if(ftp_proxy)
            proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::FtpCachingProxy);
        QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
    }
```

Now behind http squid proxy server, this code works fine in case of http urls. But, if i try to download a file with ftp url the download fails with the error

```
no suitable proxy found
```

It does not seem to use http proxy for ftp urls. But, we have such options like in firefox:

```
use this proxy server for all protocols
```

How to do similar thing in Qt!

**Update:**

```
void DownloadThread::startDownload()
```

{
    QString args =downUrl,tempFN;

```
QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded(args.toLocal8Bit());

request.setUrl(url);
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute, true);
reply.setCookieJar(cookieJar);
reply=manager.get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,
            SLOT(saveToDisk()));
...
```

}

Comment: What does your subsequent network request look like. Please provide a small code fragment of how you are issuing the request.

Comment: What do you actually set for setApplicationProxy() when it's ftp_proxy case? 
I have a feeling the firefox option simply sets all proxy variants to the same value as the http: proxy one, so you should be doing the same in your case.

Comment: Hi Adnan,

Have you tried explicitly setting the Qftp proxy? 

`int setProxy ( const QString & host, quint16 port ) `

That might get you more joy, but yes, you have to set the proxies up for each connection normally, however, there is always the possibility that the proxy you are trying to use doesn't support FTP?  If you pass me some more details about the proxy and where your problems lie (request/response code for example)  I will do my best to help out:)

Comment: @GMasucci Thanks! I am behind a squid http proxy. All ftp downloads work fine through firefox but fail through Qt. I am updating the code

Comment: Did that do the trick then? You up and running now?:)

Comment: It is 2017 now, this problem is still actual. I'm shocked, to be honest. Setting proxy for Qftp (it is deprecated now and is in a separate project) brings no result. The solution from here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30535 does not help also, it works only for http protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting the Qftp proxy?

```
int setProxy ( const QString & host, quint16 port )
```

That might get you more joy, but yes, you have to set the proxies up for each connection normally, however, there is always the possibility that the proxy you are trying to use doesn't support FTP?  If you pass me some more details about the proxy and where your problems lie (request/response code for example)

Also in squid.conf may want to change/add the following in case they are not present

```
acl SSL_ports port 443 21
acl FTP proto FTP
always_direct allow FTP
http_access allow ftp
```

Also, worth checking that the firewall allows **port 20, 21 & 443** (I know its a simple check, but often I find its things like these that can be a real pain to find as a root cause).

Do you have a copy of the log file that is generated? it would be interesting/helpful to see what error code is being returned.  Also, have you tried manually stepping through the program to see what is contained in the variables at run-time, that would give you a better picture of what is happening, as it may be that everything is fine and that there is a simple way to progress which the contents of the variables will lead you to in short order (might not be the case but it usually worth a try).

Comment: ahem apologies, my answer previously went to a comment. still getting used to social media.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing so much interest. Actually, i am on holiday these days. I will reply to soon as i get back.

Comment: Added a couple more squid.conf entries that may help, don't know how I forgot them the first time sorry.

Comment: It didn't work, the problem comes only with QNetworkAccessManager, browsers and other download managers work fine

Comment: In your current setup does any other ftp client allow traffic through the squid ftp proxy?  If so then you would need to examine the code more closely, perhaps also try a non-qt approach to verify that all is well with everything in the proxy setup as well.  Could also check that the auhentication protocols match in your code and in squid, as this can be an issue sometimes.